# Allowing HTML in block title - where is $block->subject created?

Tags: 7, blocks

I want to get a `<br>` tag into a block-title but by default the brackets are turned into html characters. My theme's block.tpl is

```
<h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><?php print $block->subject; ?></h2>
```

so it looks like the rendering isn't happening there. I can't find where `$block->subject` is getting processed. It's not in my theme's template.php. So where in core is `$block->subject` assembled?

Answer (score 3):

You may be interested in [Block Class Styles](http://drupal.org/project/block_class_styles), which has an additional feature:

> Allows the ability to set a global text format for custom block
>   titles; this allows you to now have HTML in your custom block titles.
>   Yes, you can now have block titles that contain HTML markup!

Answer (score 0):

Found the line in `block.module`:

`$block->subject = $block->title == '<none>' ? '' : check_plain($block->title);`

Decided to skip any fanciness and just replace `$block->subject` with `$block->title` in my `block.tpl.php`. Easy.

Comment: careful. Core does this to disallow HTML in block titles -- this is to avoid an authorized user from creating content that contains HTML to cross-link titles to malicious domains.

Comment: Thanks, yes. This is for a site with only trusted users. Is there a better filter for html that still lets `<br>` tags through?

Comment: Drupal doesnt care about "trusted users". It assumes everyone is potentially malicious -- because your site could be hacked and an un-trusted user could submit a blog post, or create a block for instance.

Dont get me wrong -- I've done something similiar for a project as well. As a CMS drupal sanitizes all "titles" that come from user input.

Comment: Right, that's what I meant - the users are trusted by me, not necessarily Drupal. :)

Answer (score 0):

i went this route without having to hack core or install another module. this solution is good if you just need to insert a limited amount of html. in my case i just wanted to surround the text with an em> tag for styling purposes.

i made a new tpl file to override block.tpl.php in my templates folder and I added in the following:

```
<div id="<?php print $block_html_id; ?>" class="<?php print $classes; ?>"<?php print $attributes; ?>> 

  <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
<?php if ($block->subject): ?>
  <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>> 

  <?php 

  $xtitle = preg_replace('/\*\*/', '<em>', $block->subject, 1); 
  $xtitle = preg_replace('/\*\*/', '</em>', $xtitle, 1); 

  print $xtitle; 

  ?>

  </h2>
<?php endif;?>
  <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

  <div class="content"<?php print $content_attributes; ?>> 
    <?php print $content ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

All I'm doing is just doing a string replacement for * * . Now i can just surround my titles with ** if i want to add the em> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an [if](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) or [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) statement at the top of [block.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.tpl.php/7) to match the unique block delta and then you can change the value of `$block->subject`:

`if($block->delta == 'BLOCK_DELTA'){
    $block->subject = t('A title with some HTML');
}`

Install [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) and the use `kpr($block->delta);` to find out what the delta is.

Don't forget to pass the title through the [t function](https://www.drupal.org/node/322774).